# TypeError (intermediate value ) is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make my react native app as a graphql client, I used to use redux and I'm adding graphql. I'm facing an error, the picture indicates it.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { apolloReducer } from 'apollo-cache-redux';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import ReduxLink from 'apollo-link-redux';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { accountReducer } from './account.reducer';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';

const persistConfiguration = { key: 'spottd', storage: AsyncStorage };
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ accountReducer, apolloReducer });
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfiguration, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const cache = new new InMemoryCache();
const reduxLink = new ReduxLink(store);
const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri: `https://dcef73ba.ngrok.io/graphql` });

const errorLink = onError((errors) => { console.log(errors); });
const link = ApolloLink.from([ reduxLink, errorLink, httpLink, ]);
const client = new ApolloClient({ link, cache });

export default store;
export { link, client }
```

[image: Error]

Comment: `new new InMemoryCache()`?

Comment: Thank you ! I'm just stupid, I haven't see the mistake